# centos make error: make: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by make)

Tags: terminal, centos, gnu-make, glibc

I have installed `make`, but when I use or check the version, it comes to this error.

```
[user@ip /home/my_id]
$make
make: /lib64/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by make)
make: /lib64/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by make)
make: /lib64/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by make) 
make: /lib64/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by make)

$make -v
make: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by make) 
make: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by make)
make: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by make) 
make: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by make)
```

I have tried to install `GLIBC_2.27` and etc, but too install these packets also need to use `make`(command as follow, line 7) and I come back to the problem above.

```
tar zxvf glibc-2.27.tar.gz
tar zxvf glibc-ports-2.27.tar.gz
mkdir build
cd build
../glibc-2.27/configure  --prefix=/usr --disable-profile --enable-add-ons --with-headers=/usr/include --with-binutils=/usr/bin
make -j4
make install
```

I have tried to install `GLIBC_2.27` and etc, but install these packets also need to use `make`(command as follow, line 7) and come back to the problem above.

```
tar zxvf glibc-2.27.tar.gz
tar zxvf glibc-ports-2.27.tar.gz
mkdir build
cd build
../glibc-2.27/configure  --prefix=/usr --disable-profile --enable-add-ons --with-headers=/usr/include --with-binutils=/usr/bin
make -j4
make install
```

How can I solve this error?

Can I use `make` without using `GLIBC_2.27 and etc.`? On other machines, they also only support `GLIBC_2.12`, but they can use `make` successfully.

Comment: However you installed make, which you didn't specify, was not the right way to do it.  You've installed a `make` binary that was built for a different, newer, distribution of Linux than the one you're using.  You generally can't take programs that were compiled for NEWER versions of the OS, and run them on OLDER versions of the OS (the opposite, running programs built for OLDER versions on NEWER versions, usually does work).  Do not try to change your libc version!!  That way lies pain and disaster never-ending.  Instead, delete that version of make and go get the one for your distro.

Answer (score 1):

> I have installed make

You have installed a `make` binary that was built on a newer system than the one you have. Don't do *that* -- instead install a `make` binary that was built *for* your distribution (usually using your package manager, e.g. `sudo yum install make`).

> I have tried to install GLIBC_2.27 and etc

Don't do *that* either -- any mistakes you make will likely render your system unbootable.